# Testing HTTPS locally with Coldfusion

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, https, coldfusion-9, cfml

I would like to test https related development on my local machine before pushing it to staging and production.

The current url is: `http://localhost:8500/mysite/index.cfm` which works fine

If I try and modify it to https, the page just loads and loads and nothing happens (in chrome it gets to the "This webpage is not available" page)

I have googled for information relating to this, but have not found anything helpful. The only information I have found was related to older versions of CF. From that I have created a my.keystore file, but am not sure what to do with it in CF9.

If any information could be provided that would assist me in setting this up / getting it working and testing, I would be extremely grateful . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install IIS / Apache, hook ColdFusion into the webserver, then install the SSL certificate locally.

Personally I think it's best to replicate production as close as possible in development so I am not a fan of using the inbuilt server and always use a webserver.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to enable SSL on the built in JRUN webserver follow the steps described here: [Enabling SSL on the ColdFusion 8 built-in web server](http://www.cfchimp.com/wordpress/2008/08/enabling-ssl-on-the-coldfusion-8-built-in-web-server/). Make sure to read the comments section especially what it says about the JVM arguments. Same procedure should work for ColdFusion 9.

Personally I second Paul's answer and would recommend using IIS or Apache, even in a development environment.

Comment: Thanks - as per your comment I voted you up, but gave him the answer. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use IIS7 and use the Self-Signed Certificates property. You can refer to the URL below to do the self Certificates.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx